# Flutter - Sign Firebase token with Auth0

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, auth0

When signing in to Firebase (for example with Google) and returning the token, how to make that token signed by Auth0?

Answer (score 0):

When signing to FireBase, you provide credentials (userid/pass etc) to FireBase and FireBase returns a signed token. That the core functionality of FireBase. Because then onwards you don't even need FireBase. You just verify on each resource access that the token was actually issued by FireBase and is valid by running JWT checks.

Let say you make FireBase to sign the token using Auth0, then its basically would be a login to Auth0 and not FireBase
and what functionality are you use to the FireBase for then.

The good use case for it would be to use multi factor logins or other flow of login where firebase is already hardcoded in the front (which is rare)

Comment: Exactly, I thought the same, but this post says otherwise:
https://auth0.com/blog/developing-real-time-apps-with-firebase-and-firestore/#Setting-Up-Auth0

Anyway, I have to do it this way.

Comment: yes they allow, although the use case of that would be rare. adjusted the answer to make it more useful for others. @fl